# Not able to deploy kjar created from eclipse into jbpm 6.2.0 console

Tags: jbpm

I am new to JBPM 6.2 and I am trying to deploy a process that is created in eclipse to jbpm console. these are the steps that i followed. Is there anything that is missing or wrong in what I am doing?

- Created a JBPM(maven) project in eclipse.
- Modified `groupid` and `artifactid` in `pom.xml`
- maven clean, install.
- artifact created in target folder.
- uploaded artifact into console.
- tried to deploy, but got error saying kbase not found.
- after some googling, updated `kmodule.xml`, changed version in `pom.xml`
  and mvn clean , install again
- uploaded artifact into console
- And this time when I try to install, it is giving below error.

`server.log`

```
2015-06-27 20:08:36,482 INFO  [org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2Servlet] (default task-23) POST request received.
2015-06-27 20:09:15,732 INFO  [org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl] (default task-34) Deploying unit com.myprocess:HelloWorld:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2015-06-27 20:09:19,407 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (default task-34) KieModule was added: ZipKieModule[releaseId=com.myprocess:HelloWorld:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT,file=C:\Users\XXXXX\.m2\repository\com\myprocess\HelloWorld\1.0.1-SNAPSHOT\HelloWorld-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]
2015-06-27 20:09:21,901 INFO  [org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.store.DeploymentSynchronizer] (default task-34) Deployment unit com.myprocess:HelloWorld:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT removed successfully
2015-06-27 20:09:21,921 ERROR [org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContext] (default task-34) JAXB context instance could not be found when undeploying deployment 'com.myprocess:HelloWorld:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'!
2015-06-27 20:09:21,925 WARN  [org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService] (default task-34) Unexpected error while deploying unit com.myprocess:HelloWorld:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to instantiate JAXBContext for deployment 'com.myprocess:HelloWorld:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'.
    at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.AbstractDeploymentService.commonDeploy(AbstractDeploymentService.java:159) [jbpm-kie-services-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:152) [jbpm-kie-services-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source) [jbpm-services-cdi-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:179) [jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-backend-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:143) [jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-backend-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source) [jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-backend-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.AbstractRPCMethodCallback.invokeMethodFromMessage(AbstractRPCMethodCallback.java:48) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.VoidRPCEndpointCallback.callback(VoidRPCEndpointCallback.java:20) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.RemoteServiceCallback.callback(RemoteServiceCallback.java:54) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints$2.callback(CDIExtensionPoints.java:396) [errai-weld-integration-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.DeliveryPlan.deliver(DeliveryPlan.java:47) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.ServerMessageBusImpl.sendGlobal(ServerMessageBusImpl.java:293) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.SimpleDispatcher.dispatchGlobal(SimpleDispatcher.java:46) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ErraiServiceImpl.store(ErraiServiceImpl.java:97) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ErraiServiceImpl.store(ErraiServiceImpl.java:114) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.DefaultBlockingServlet.doPost(DefaultBlockingServlet.java:142) [errai-bus-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecureHeadersFilter.java:53) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.5.0.Final.jar:0.5.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SecurityIntegrationFilter.java:64) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.5.0.Final.jar:0.5.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:27) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to instantiate JAXBContext for deployment 'com.myprocess:HelloWorld:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'.
    at org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContext.setupDeploymentJaxbContext(DynamicJaxbContext.java:224) [kie-remote-services-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContext.setupDeploymentJaxbContext(DynamicJaxbContext.java:155) [kie-remote-services-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.TransactionalObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(TransactionalObserverNotifier.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.kie.remote.services.cdi.DeploymentInfoBean.addOnDeploy(DeploymentInfoBean.java:66) [kie-remote-services-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:165) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.TransactionalObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(TransactionalObserverNotifier.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:119) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:112) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:83) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl.notifyOnDeploy(DeploymentServiceCDIImpl.java:87) [jbpm-services-cdi-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.AbstractDeploymentService.commonDeploy(AbstractDeploymentService.java:151) [jbpm-kie-services-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "getTasksForProcessCommand". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.jbpm.services.task.admin.listener.GetTasksForProcessCommand
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.GetTasksForProcessCommand
        at private org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommand org.jbpm.services.task.commands.CompositeCommand.mainCommand
        at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.CompositeCommand
Two classes have the same XML type name "jaxbTaskSummary". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.impl.task.JaxbTaskSummary
        at private java.util.List org.kie.remote.services.jaxb.JaxbTaskSummaryListResponse.taskSummaryList
        at org.kie.remote.services.jaxb.JaxbTaskSummaryListResponse
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.xml.JaxbTaskSummary

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jboss-1.jar:2.2.5.jboss-1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jboss-1.jar:2.2.5.jboss-1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jboss-1.jar:2.2.5.jboss-1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jboss-1.jar:2.2.5.jboss-1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jboss-1.jar:2.2.5.jboss-1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jboss-1.jar:2.2.5.jboss-1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:392) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:618) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:565) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContext.setupDeploymentJaxbContext(DynamicJaxbContext.java:220) [kie-remote-services-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    ... 90 more
```

`kmodule.xml`

```xml
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
  <kbase name="defaultKieBase" default="true" eventProcessingMode="cloud" equalsBehavior="identity" declarativeAgenda="disabled" scope="javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped" packages="*">
    <ksession name="defaultKieSession" type="stateful" default="true" clockType="realtime" beliefSystem="simple" scope="javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped"/>
    <ksession name="defaultStatelessKieSession" type="stateless" default="true" clockType="realtime" beliefSystem="simple" scope="javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped"/>
  </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myprocess</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>jBPM :: Sample Maven Project</name>
  <description>A sample jBPM Maven project</description>

  <properties>
    <jbpm.version>6.1.0.Final</jbpm.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbpm-test</artifactId>
      <version>${jbpm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I just managed to resolve it.

If we take the following snippet from the exception stacktrace:

Two classes have the same XML type name "jaxbTaskSummary". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.impl.task.JaxbTaskSummary
        at private java.util.List org.kie.remote.services.jaxb.JaxbTaskSummaryListResponse.taskSummaryList
        at org.kie.remote.services.jaxb.JaxbTaskSummaryListResponse
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.xml.JaxbTaskSummary

The class org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.impl.task.JaxbTaskSummary is in the is in the kie-remote-jaxb-6.1.0.Final.jar and the class org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.xml.JaxbTaskSummary I suspect is in the jbpm-human-task-core-6.1.0.Final.jar.

In my case I did NOT need the kie-remote-client-6.2.0.Final.jar in my jBPM process project so I removed the dependency from the pom file and I successfully deployed my process to the jBPM console.

There should never be a reason to have both the kie-remote-jaxb jar and the jbpm-human-task-core jar in the same pom file declaration as the kie-remote-jaxb jar should be used on the client that is going to interact with your business process remotely and the jbpm-human-task-core jar should reside on the server-side, where your business process is deployed. If you find you still need the kie-remote-jaxb jar, you can use a maven dependency scope like test to prevent this jar being deployed along with your business process.

Going forward run a mvn dependency:tree on your project and figure out which jar is pulling in the kie-remote-jaxb jar. Try and exclude the kie-remote-jaxb jar from being pulled in by using a maven exclusion. If you find you still need this jar on your classpath for some reason the use the maven dependency scope mechanism described earlier to prevent this jar being deployed along with your business process.

Please remember to run a mvn clean install on your project after you apply the changes recommended above.